# Sending Data From Single Html Page to multi php pages using ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I Want To Ask May I use Ajax to send data to multi pages phph
i have 2 buttons in an HTML from and i want each button to send data to different php pages using ajax from the same html page

Comment: just three $.post lines in the click function???

Answer (score 0):

Ya.. You can make this.. if the functionality is different, you need to give individual AJAX request for each page..  if the functionality is same, you can change the URL dynamically and send with the single AJAX request...

Comment: i tried to send data using 2 buttons
each button will call javascript function to send data to php pages
using ajax without refresh the page
my question is how to deal with ajax in this case
as each button will use ajax